# how to encode non-ascii characters in java script?

Tags: javascript

Suppose
ch = á
expected output is = \u00e1
but
current output = %E1 when I use escape(ch) and
current output = %C3%A1 when I use encodeURIComponent(ch)

I am using API which accept unicode characters.

Comment: Encode? What for? Encoding is not an absolute. If the API accepts Unicode characters, why encode at all?

Answer (score 0):

try utf8 encoding for the characters. Here is code:

```
https://code.google.com/p/archfirst/source/browse/trunk/html/apps/bfclient-jquery-backbone/js/libs/utf8_encode.js?r=1029
```

Answer (score 0):

> ch = á expected output is = \u00e1

Do *never* use `escape`. Do use `encodeURIComponent` for `x-www-form-urlencode`ing forms for POST or GET HTTP request.

For the output you want, use `JSON.stringify`. It will give you a valid JSON string (including delimiters and escaped delimiters), with all special characters encoded by an escape sequence.